# User profile sync error

Tags: 2010, profile-sync

I am trying to sync users from our AD to SharePoint. Currently I can not start user profile import because I get the following error all the time.

Error

**"Cannot navigate to the requested page while User Profile Synchronization is running. Please wait for the current Sychronization run to finish"**

The error is clear but this error is showing up all the time for a week now; is there a way to stop it or what am I doing wrong? I have restarted the server with no luck.

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you running?  How many servers?  Are you using domain accounts for each of the services?

Comment: sorry for lack of info. Sharepoint 2010,farm server-not standalone,yes one domain account for all sp services

Comment: Please don't forget to put the version of SharePoint as a tag in your questions.

Comment: whats the current build of the farm, or latest CU installed?

Answer (score 4):

Please read this article by Harbar: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx there are full definition of your problem and ways to resolve it

Comment: Thanks Vitaly,i'll try and write what happens.It looks like a very detailed and informative post.

Comment: This is an excellent article.  I saved it out in case it ever goes offline!

Answer (score 2):

Open the MIISClient:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Check for any detailed error messages and cancel the current run.

Comment: it says unable to connect to Syn. Serv.
some possible reasons are:
the service is not started.
your account is not a member of a required security group.

my account is domain and local pc admin btw.

Comment: Corbett's suggestion to add your account to FIMSyncOperator worked when I encountered the error opening miisclient

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making sure the FIM services are started, to open the miisclient you may need to add your account to the FIMSyncOperators group, log off and on.

Comment: This is true, but not directly related to the question.

Comment: I do not have FIMSyncOperators group neither on server or AD